# Twilio Task Router: Multiple reservation not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter, twilio-conference

I am using Twilio task router.

I have added the Task Queue configuration like this

[image]

Now multiple workers are allowed to get the reservation. Then I am dequeuing the call like this.

```
return response()->json([
 "instruction" => "dequeue",
 "status_callback_events" => "initiated,ringing,answered,completed",
 "status_callback_url" => url('ivr/statuseventCallback'),
]);
```

Multiple workers are getting the call but when someone attends the call. Other workers still get the rining.

I want the ringing to stop when the call is attended by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is by design. You are instructing the Taskrouter to try five different workers and assign it to the first who answers. All five workers' phones have to ring in order to assign it to someone.

The alternative is to use the Taskrouter Javascript SDK. The taskrouter.js client has a [worker event listener](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk-v1/workspace/worker#worker-events) that will send a notification to the worker upon assignment of a potential task, ask the worker to accept the task, and then dial the worker. The first worker to accept will have their phone ring. The others who did not accept, will not.

Comment: That is the issue. It is still ringing to other workers even first worker accepted the task using JS SDK.

Comment: This is by design as explained in more detail here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/route-tasks-even-faster-with-taskrouter-multi-reservation-html. This is the tradeoff. The customer receives a worker "faster" but the workers all get a chance to accept the task and thereforce hear ringing. If you only want 1 worker to ring then set Maximum Reserved Workers to 1 (which is the default). This will let Taskrouter handle the assignment of the task and only have 1 worker's phone ring.